# How to make dependent Input fields in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make three input edit texts that depend on each other i.e Country, State, City that depend on each other in kotlin android. I want when country is picked in the country input, the states in the selected country should show in the state input.
Any one with an idea how i can achieve this?

I am new to Kotlin and have no idea where to start from

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional the check whether country is selected or not

```
if(condition){
    // condition is true
   // You can show and hide views by using: findViewById<EditText>(R.id.myeditText).visibility = View.GONE or View.Visible
} else {
   // condition is true
}
```

These statements will be your best friend